# Sedov-Taylor blastwave resources

Tags: resource-recommendations, explosions, supernova, shock-waves

What are some resources for learning about [blast waves](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blast_wave)?  Particularly the [Sedov-Taylor](http://www.google.com/search?as_epq=sedov+taylor) solution?  The specific application is modeling supernovae.

Comment: Have you tried G.B. Whitham's book _Linear and Nonlinear Waves_ or Rybicki and Lightman's _Radiative Processes in Astrophysics_?